# Selenium Webdriver - How to trigger a function if a button is clicked

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Supposedly this is the id for a 'SAVE' button...

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_cbpAssociationNe_btnNewItemTopCreationSave_CD > span.dx-vam" )).click();
```

if this 'SAVE' button is clicked I have to trigger a function(). I'm a js programmer we use 'onClick' event but here in selenium webdriver it's not working.

Also how to use 'if' loop for this type of  condition, I have tried this out but it's not working.

```
if(driver.findElement(By. cssSelector("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_cbpAssociationNew_btnNewItemTopCreationSave_CD > span.dx-vam" )).click())
```

Comment: Selenium should trigger a javascript `onclick()` event when the button is clicked.  I'd have to see the HTML of the button to be sure, but it looks like you're clicking a `span`, not a `button`.  If the `span` contains the button, keep in mind that Selenium clicks in the center of the element, which may not include the part you want to click.

Comment: @Richard What you said is correct here is the HTML code(<span class="dx-vam">Save</span> ). It clicks the span element. So what would be the solution for this....

Comment: have you tried `xpath` ?

Comment: At a guess, I would try clicking the element that contains the `onclick()` event.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code for clicking on the 'SAVE' button:-
`driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_cbpAssociationNew_btnNewItemTopCreationSave_CD")).click();`

And, the `click())` method returns **void** not **boolean**, and hence you cannot use it as a condition inside a **if loop**.